# Change Bootstraps column order for mobile while inside a loop

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-4

Trying to change Bootstraps column order for mobile, .col-order doesn't work cause its in a loop. Have $loop->iteration set for displaying different backgrounds on column 1, 4 or 5 for desktop, but for mobile i need some way of displaying them stacked as odds or evens, thanks.

```
<div class="row no-gutters bg-light">
     @foreach ($products as $product)
     <div class="col-12 col-xl-6 div-wo-bg @if($loop->iteration === 1 || $loop->iteration === 4 || $loop->iteration === 5) div-w-bg @endif">
```

Have tried an if statement:

```
<div class="row no-gutters bg-light">
     @foreach ($products as $product)
         @if ('className' == 'col-12')
            <div class="col-12 col-xl-6 div-wo-bg @if($loop->iteration === 1 || $loop->iteration === 4 || $loop->iteration === 5) div-w-bg @endif">
         @elseif ('className' == 'col-xl-6')
            <div class="col-12 col-xl-6 div-wo-bg @if($loop->odd) div-w-bg @endif">
         @endif
```

This just throws all the column display out of wack (for both mobile and desktop).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!-- Latest Products Showcase Section 

         - The showcase design calls for columns to be side by side for desktop, but stacked for mobile. There are 2 differently styled   bg's repeated throughout the layout of the columns.

         - Because these columns are layed out differently, they both require 2 different $loop extensions to retrieve the bg's. So       from within an if statement we use $loop->iteration for desktop but $loop->odd for mobile -->

    <!-- Desktop Layout -->
        <div class="container-fluid p-0">
            <div class="row showcase-shop-products no-gutters bg-light">
                @foreach ($products as $product)
                    <div class="col-6 d-none d-lg-flex div-wo-bg @if($loop->iteration === 1 || $loop->iteration === 4 || $loop->iteration === 5) div-w-bg @endif">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div class="row">

                                <!-- Column a (Text) --> 
                                <div class="col-6 showcase-col">
                                    <div class="overlay"></div>
                                    <div class="showcase-hero">
                                        <h2 class="card-title mb-4"><a href="{{ route("shop.show", $product->slug) }}">{{ $product->name }}</a></h2>
                                        <h3 class="card-subtitle text-muted">{{ $product->details }}</h3>
                                        <h4 class="mb-3">{{ $product->presentPrice() }}</h4>
                                        <p class="card-text mb-4 d-lg-none d-xxl-block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. At dicta accusamus quia aliquid minima animi alias.</p>
                                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary rounded" role="button">Add to Cart</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <!-- Column b (Image) -->
                                <div class="col-6 showcase-col">
                                    <a href="{{ route("shop.show", $product->slug) }}" class="text-center showcase-hero"><img class="card-img-top products-img img-fluid" src="{{ asset("img/shop/products/".$product->slug.".png") }}" alt="Random product item"></a>
                                    <div class="overlay"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                @endforeach 
            </div>
        </div>   

    <!-- Mobile Layout -->
        <div class="container-fluid p-0">
            <div class="row showcase-shop-products no-gutters bg-light">
                @foreach ($products as $product)
                    <div class="col-12 d-flex d-lg-none div-wo-bg @if($loop->odd) div-w-bg @endif">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div class="row">

                                <!-- Top Column (Image) -->
                                <div class="col-12 showcase-col">
                                    <a href="{{ route("shop.show", $product->slug) }}" class="text-center showcase-hero pt-3"><img class="card-img-top products-img img-fluid" src="{{ asset("img/shop/products/".$product->slug.".png") }}" alt="Random product item"></a>
                                    <div class="overlay"></div>
                                </div>

                                <!-- Bottom Column (Text) -->
                                <div class="col-12 showcase-col">
                                    <div class="overlay"></div>
                                    <div class="showcase-hero text-center pb-5">
                                        <h2 class="card-title mb-4"><a href="{{ route("shop.show", $product->slug) }}">{{ $product->name }}</a></h2>
                                        <h3 class="card-subtitle text-muted">{{ $product->details }}</h3>
                                        <h4 class="mb-3">{{ $product->presentPrice() }}</h4>
                                        <p class="card-text mb-4 d-none xl-block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. At dicta accusamus quia aliquid minima animi alias.</p>
                                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary rounded btn-width" role="button">Add to Cart</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>
```

Works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div class="row no-gutters bg-light">
   @foreach ($products as $key => $product)
   <div class="col-12 col-xl-6 div-wo-bg {{ $key == 1 ? 'div-w-bg' : ($key == 4 ? 'div-w-bg' : ( $key == 5 ? 'div-w-bg' )) }}">
```

Comment: Thanks Aditya, but i just get error: "syntax error, unexpected ')'"